# How to pass credentials to "Windows Security" when authenticating on the web?

Tags: authentication, credentials

I needed to write a script that will pass a Username and Password to the windows security Authentication popup. This is needed to test other credentials since I do not want to use my own.

Answer (score 0):

Using VBScript, I created the following function:

```
set IE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
set WshShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.shell")

   IE.visible = 1
   IE.navigate("http://website")



   WshShell.AppActivate "Windows Internet Explorer"
   WScript.Sleep 1000
   WshShell.SendKeys "UserNAME"
   WScript.Sleep 500
   WshShell.SendKeys "{TAB}"
   WScript.Sleep 500
   WshShell.SendKeys "Password"
   WScript.Sleep 500
   WshShell.SendKeys "{TAB}"
   WScript.Sleep 500
   WshShell.SendKeys "{TAB}"
   WScript.Sleep 500
   WshShell.SendKeys "{ENTER}"
   WScript.Sleep 2000


   IE.Quit
```